# Can we used more than one html.begin in single view razor?

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

I am working on blogpost nested comments.

I have used to html.beginform one is for add new comment and another one is for reply.

My View:

```
       <fieldset class="new-comment">
            <legend class="title">@T("Blog.Comments.LeaveYourComment")</legend>
            @using (Html.BeginForm())
            {
                <div id="newcomment">
                    <div class="message-error">@Html.ValidationSummary(true)</div>
                    @{
                string result = TempData["nop.blog.addcomment.result"] as string;
                    }
                    @if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(result))
                    {
                        <div class="result">@result</div>
                    }
                    <div class="forms-box">
                        <div class="inputs">
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AddNewComment.CommentText)
                            <div class="input-box">
                                @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.AddNewComment.CommentText, new { @class = "comment-text" })
                            </div>
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AddNewComment.CommentText)
                        </div>
                        @if (Model.AddNewComment.DisplayCaptcha)
                        {
                            <div class="captcha-box">
                                @Html.Raw(Html.GenerateCaptcha())
                            </div>
                            <div class="clear">
                            </div>
                        }
                    </div>
                    <div class="clear">
                    </div>
                    <div class="buttons">
                        <input type="submit" name="add-comment" class="button-1 blog-post-add-comment-button" value="@T("Blog.Comments.SubmitButton")" />
                    </div>
                </div>


            }
        </fieldset>
```

Reply:

```
       <div class="container">

                @{//to set div id in comment list
            var Count = 0;
            var CommentParentID = 0;       }
                @using (Html.BeginForm())
                {


                    foreach (var commentlist in Model.Comments.Where(x => x.CommentParentID == 0))
                    {

                    <div class="nested-comments">



                        <div>
                            @if (commentlist.AllowViewingProfiles)
                            {
                                <a href="@Url.RouteUrl("CustomerProfile", new { id = commentlist.CustomerId })" class="username">@(commentlist.CustomerName)</a>
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                <span class="username">@(commentlist.CustomerName)</span>
                            }
                            <div class="avatar">
                                @if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(commentlist.CustomerAvatarUrl))
                                {
                                    <img src="@(commentlist.CustomerAvatarUrl)" class="avatar-img" title="avatar" alt="avatar" />
                                }
                            </div>


                            <div class="comment-content">
                                <div class="comment-time">
                                    @T("Blog.Comments.CreatedOn"): <span class="stat-value">@commentlist.CreatedOn.ToString("g")</span>

                                        <div>
                                            <div id="div_@Count" style="display: none;">
                                                @{CommentParentID = commentlist.Id;
                                                  Model.AddNewComment.CommentParentID = CommentParentID;}

                                                <div>

                                                     <div class="message-error">@Html.ValidationSummary(true)</div>
                                                @{
                                              string strresult = TempData["nop.blog.addcomment.result"] as string;                                  
                                                }
                                                @if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(strresult))
                                                {
                                                    <div class="result">@strresult</div>
                                                }
                                                    <div>
                                                        <div id="ChildComment_@Model.AddNewComment.CommentParentID">
                                                            @Html.HiddenFor(modelComment => modelComment.AddNewComment.CommentParentID)
                                                            @Html.Label("Reply Comment")
                                                            <div>
                                                                @Html.TextAreaFor(modelComment => modelComment.AddNewComment.ChildCommentText)
                                                            </div>
                                                             @Html.ValidationMessageFor(modelComment => modelComment.AddNewComment.ChildCommentText,"Please Enter Reply")
                                                        </div>

                                                        @if (Model.AddNewComment.DisplayCaptcha)
                                                        {
                                                            <div class="captcha-box">
                                                                @Html.Raw(Html.GenerateCaptcha())
                                                            </div>
                                                            <div class="clear">
                                                            </div>
                                                        }
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="clear">
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="buttons">
                                                        <input type="submit" name="reply-comment"  value="@T("Blog.Comments.ReplyButton")" />
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="clear">
                                                </div>



                                            </div>

                                            <input type="button" id="reply" class="reply-link" onclick="return showHide('div_@Count');" value="Reply" />
                                            @{Count++; }
                                        </div>

                                </div>
                                <div class="comment-body">
                                    @Html.Raw(Nop.Core.Html.HtmlHelper.FormatText(commentlist.CommentText, false, true, false, false, false, false))
                                </div>
                            </div>


                            <div class="clear">
                            </div>


                            @foreach (var cmt in Model.Comments.Where(x => x.CommentParentID == commentlist.Id))
                            {
                                <div class="comment">
                                    <div>
                                        <div class="user-info">
                                            @if (cmt.AllowViewingProfiles)
                                            {
                                                <a href="@Url.RouteUrl("CustomerProfile", new { id = cmt.CustomerId })" class="username">@(cmt.CustomerName)</a>
                                            }
                                            else
                                            {
                                                <span class="username">@(cmt.CustomerName)</span>
                                            }
                                            <div class="avatar">
                                                @if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(cmt.CustomerAvatarUrl))
                                                {
                                                    <img src="@(cmt.CustomerAvatarUrl)" class="avatar-img" title="avatar" alt="avatar" />
                                                }
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="comment-content">
                                        <div class="comment-time">
                                            @T("Blog.Comments.CreatedOn"): <span class="stat-value">@cmt.CreatedOn.ToString("g")</span>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="comment-body">
                                            @Html.Raw(Nop.Core.Html.HtmlHelper.FormatText(cmt.CommentText, false, true, false, false, false, false))
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                </div>
                            }
                            @Html.Widget("blogpost_page_inside_comment")

                        </div>
                    </div>

                    }

                }

            </div>
```

When i click on Reply button i am not able to get parameter value for 
modelComment => modelComment.AddNewComment.ChildCommentText

Comment: You can use multiple html.beginform(). It's only generating a <form> tag. Of course, you can't have nested form tags though.

Comment: @Anonymous:is above code correct?

Comment: @NetraWable can you see any errors

Comment: @Karthik: no,i didnot get any error

Comment: @Karthik:Can you give me some sample links to refer?

Comment: What does the action look like?

Comment: @NetraWable post your controller actions

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can have more than one form on a page, as long as one is not nested inside the other one.

What happens when you debug? Does it go to the correct Action and just not pass any values?

Comment: :It goes to correct Action i did not get any error but the value which i am expection on submittion of reply is null.